# Warning message: In mean.default(., lead_time) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Tags: r, warnings, numeric

I run into this problem.

The thing is, the column I am using is actually a numeric column and I get correct results using:

```
mean(hotel_bookings_city$lead_time).
```

but when I try this:

```
hotel_bookings_city %>% mean(lead_time)
```

I receive the warning that the column 'lead_time' is not numeric/logical even though it is.

What am I not doing right?

Answer (score 0):

As @Ritchi Sacramento stated already, in your second approach, the hole data.frame is passed as first argument to mean because of the use of the dpyr operator `%>%`. This you can notice also in your warning where the point refers to the actual (eventually by former lines of `%>%` modified) version of your original data.frame.

You can solve the problem with the code @Ritchi Sacramento suggested already, by (1) defining the column to modify before applying `mean` or (2) with the function `summarise`.

Another approach which might be more similar to your original approach is to use the pull-function:

```
hotel_bookings_city %>% 
   pull(lead_time) %>% 
   mean()
```